# Fit contours to a circle

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to fit some circle like contours in OpenCV to a perfect circle, just like on the figure above.

The contours that I'm trying to fit are just like the one in this pic.

[image]

I'm trying to do it by using `HoughCircles` function but it too imprecise results. Someone know any way to do it properly without using OpenCV `HoughCircles` function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find contour in the image.
2. Use minimum enclosing circle for the contour.

See opencv example [Drawing enclosing circle and bounging box for contour](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)